# HTML encoded URL not working with apache 2.4.2

Tags: html-encode, apache2.4

I have some URLs with special characters, they all are working fine on apache 2.2.4 but breaking on apache 2.4.2.
This is one URL /%7Chier.3%5EFirst~group%5E/logo?(actual URL is /%7Chier.3^First~group^/logo?).
Can someone please help me why this working fine on apache 2.2.4 but breaking on apache 2.4.2?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what errors you see. And why are you on obscenely low maintenance levels of two different releases?

Comment: I have a similar issues - Apache 2.4.7 is ok but on 2.4.18 they fail. Did you ever resolve?

Comment: There was code to replace "%5E" with '^', this was working fine on my CentOS-5 server but was broken on CentOS-6 server. So issue was resolve by fixing below code.

char *p;
while (( q = strstr (URL, "%5E")))
{
     p = q+3;
     *q = '^';
     strcpy(q+1, p);
}

At first it seemed due to Apache because it was Apache 2.2 on my CentOS-5 and Apache 2.4 on CentOS-6, but had nothing to do with Apache.